# fill div with fixed aspect ratio with image and borders

Tags: html, image, css

I am trying to fill a div with an img inside the div by adding borders to the image.

The general structure looks like the following:

```
<div class="teaseritem">
  <a href="20180427_Feedback/index.html" class="teaserlink" title="Zur Detailansicht von ">
    <p class="category">some category</p>               
    <img src="../../pool/images/program/20180427_Feedback.png" class="img-responsive img-hover" alt="20180427_Feedback">
    <p class="date">some date</p>
    <h3>some headline</h3>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.teaser .flexbox .teaseritem a {
  display: block;
}
p.category {
  background-color: #222222;
  color: #f5f6f5;
  position: relative;
  padding: 7.5px 0 7.5px 15px;
}
.teaser .flexbox .teaseritem a .img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

(I hope I got all relevant CSS rules.)

The div should always have a aspect ratio 1:1. So the borders should be added left/right or bottom/top depending of from the source materials aspect ratio.

Unfortunatly I cannot set the width of the div to a specific pixel value because the overall size depends on the screen resolution.
I am trying to avoid unsing Javascript to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you add the img src HTML code and the additional CSS as to what you've tried so far please?

Comment: Could you please provide some actual code with CSS, making it [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: I edited the original post and added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS background-image for this kind of thing.

Comment: Ok. Using the image itself or the border color als background?